# Селект бокс из jQuery библиотеки "select2" скачет в разные стороны на мобильной версии, помогите плиз

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

На этой странице wp.html5dev.ru/shops в мобильной версии можно увидеть суть проблемы.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#cityshops').select2();
  $('.catalog-filter__box').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('is-flds-opened')) {
      $(this).removeClass('is-flds-opened');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('is-flds-opened');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.js-shop-letter {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

#h3shops {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #2b2b2b;
  text-transform: none;
}

.city.shops.select2-hidden-accessible>option {
  color: #2b2b2b;
  font-family: 'PT Serif';
  font-style: italic;
  width: 256px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: transparent;
  outline: 0 none;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

span.select2-selection.select2-selection--single {
  width: 280px;
}

.catalog-filter__fields.js-scroll.scroll-content.sex label,
.catalog-filter__fields.js-scroll.scroll-content.price label {
  color: #2b2b2b;
  font-family: 'PT Serif';
  font-style: italic;
  width: 256px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: 400;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: transparent;
  outline: 0 none;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.select2-selection__rendered,
span .select2-results {
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: "PT Serif";
  font-style: italic;
}

.select2-results__option {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

li.select2-results__option.select2-results__option--highlighted:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #ff7c7d;
}

li.select2-results__option.select2-results__option--highlighted {
  background: #fff;
  color: #2b2b2b;
}

select.city.shops::selection {
  color: #2b2b2b;
  background: #fff;
}

select.city.shops:focus {
  border-color: #000;
  background: #fff;
}

.list-brands .nav_brands li.color-letter.active {
  color: #ff7c7d;
}

#simply-form>fieldset.catalog-filter__box.filter_flds_city>div>div.scroll-wrapper.catalog-filter__fields.js-scroll.scroll-content>div.catalog-filter__fields.js-scroll.scroll-content>select {
  color: #2b2b2b;
  font-family: 'PT Serif';
  font-style: italic;
  width: 256px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: transparent;
  outline: 0 none;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option--highlighted[aria-selected] {
  background: #fff;
  color: #2b2b2b;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[aria-selected=true] {
  background: #fff;
}

.catalog-filter__btns button.reset {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .d-col_lg_9 {
    width: 68%;
    margin-left: 65px;
  }
}

@media screen (min-width: 1201px) {
  .d-col_lg_9 {
    width: 72%;
    margin-left: 25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<fieldset class="catalog-filter__box filter_flds_city">
  <h2 class="h1 catalog-filter__toggle">Город<i class="fa fa-angle-right d-hidden d-show_md"></i></h2>

  <div class="scroll-wrapper catalog-filter__fields js-scroll" style="position: relative;">
    <div class="catalog-filter__fields js-scroll" style="height: auto; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-right: 0px; max-height: 117px;">
      <select name="city" id="cityshops" class="city shops">
                        <option value="" selected></option>
                            <option value="0"></option>
                            <option value="1">Первый</option>
                            <option value="2">Второй</option>
                            <option value="3">Третий</option>
                            <option value="4">Четвертый</option>
                            <option value="5">Пятый</option>
                            <option value="6">Шестой</option>
                            <option value="7">Седьмой</option>
                    </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте

```
.select2({width: '100%'});
```